# error creating registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ts\OpenWithProgids. RegCreateKeyEx faild: code 5 Access denied

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, registry, vscode-extensions

When I open VSCode on Windows 10, I get the following pop-up window message and it requires an action:

```
error creating registry key: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ts\OpenWithProgids 
RegCreateKeyEx faild: code 5 
Access denied
```

Why this happens? What does it mean and how can I get ride of it?

I also checked the "run vscode as administrator" on compatibility tab and it asks for "run as administrator" each time I open it, and I grant the access, but still after few seconds the pop-up window appears again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error when I install VSCode but the version 64 bit "User Installer".

[image: Installing VSCode User Installer]

I had to download the version 64 bit "System Installer" and the problem has been solved.

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

[image: Select system installer]